# Dynamically rotating dataLabels icons/glyhps

Tags: svg, highcharts, rotation

I'm plotting various weather data types, and am using Erik Flower's weather icons font set's wind arrow (.wi-wind, \u0b1) icon to represent wind direction.  I'm trying, without success, to rotate them based on the direction.  He as provided a style sheet that can handle the rotation, but I don't think that applies in highcharts.

Wind dir is a scatter plot being plotted on a single axis, with height of 0 so they all line up horizontally.  When I apply rotation to the dataLabel symbols, via `dataLabel.attr({ rotation: point.y });` in a `$.each()` loop, they rotate, but end up all wavy instead of along a horizontal line.  I'm sure this is due to SVG rotation origin, but I cannot figure this one out.  Any help?

-B-

--- EDIT ---

Here's a link to an image example of what's going on.  Both rows are exhibiting the problem, both are using the same font/icon.  The top is a second axis over the wind speed axis displaying dataLabels of a scatter plot that is then rotated based upon the direction (this one doesn't have the 180 deg adjustment applied).  The lower are markers on a spline plot of wind speed that are rotated based upon the direction.

[alignment probs with rotated wind symbols](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Vo33jOMA2baXJvY0RWRFNwd0V5aExJdW5NcG9ZZHg5YWpZ/view?usp=docslist_api)

The below snippet includes rotation/translation attempts for both sets of symbols.  I only pulled the relevant lines.  Wind speed is series 4, direction is 5.

```js
// set wind speed data markers to symbols for direction, open circle with arrow point
//
// markers on spline
//
      chart.get('windS').update({
          marker: {
                symbol: 'text:\uf0b1'
            },   
       tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() {
                   return '<span style="color:' + this.color +'">\u25CF</span> wind: <b>' + this.y + ' kts at ' + 
                          chart.get('windD').yData[this.index] + '°</b><br/>';
                }
       }
      });

      
      // rotate the wind direction symbos to match the direction
      $.each(chart.series[4].data, function(i, point) {
            this.graphic
//                .translate(-5, 5) // centers symbol on line
                .attr({
                 // rotate symbol
                 // it's rotating at (0, 0) of the symbol's layout 20x36 rectangle
                    rotation: windIconDirection(chart.series[5].data[i].y),
//                     translateX: this.graphic.element.attributes.x,
//                     translateY: this.graphic.element.attributes.y
                });
        });
      

//
// data labels, not spline plot
//
        // adjust position of wind speed symbols
//         $.each(chart.series[4].data, function(i, point) {
//          this.dataLabel.attr({
//                 translateY: -16
//             })
//             .css({
//             });
//         });
        $.each(chart.series[5].data, function(i, point) {
         this.dataLabel.attr({
          rotation: point.y
         });
        });
```

Comment: Show us what you're doing with an example as a stack snippet or a jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us know how your chart looks like. Meantime check our demo which rotate wind symbols. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-meteogram#http://www.yr.no/place/United_Kingdom/England/London/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml